# Error to create a brand new table

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to create a brand new table with codes:

```
MySQL [distributor]> create table order
    -> (
    -> order_num integer  not null,
    -> order_date datetime not null,
    -> cust_id chat(10) not null
    -> );
```

It generates errors:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order
(
order_num integer  not null,
order_date datetime not null,
cust_id chat(' at line 1
```

I have checked multiple times to ensure there no problems in my codes since SQL is case-insensitive.

What's the bug with my code?

Comment: `ORDER` is a reserved word in MySQL

Comment: Also `chat` should be `CHAR`

Comment: could you please transmit your comment to the answer for the further reference? @Nick

Comment: I've done so below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your query: Firstly, `order` is a MySQL reserved word. Secondly, you have `chat` which should be `char`. Try this instead (renaming table to `orders`):

```
CREATE TABLE orders
(
order_num integer  not null,
order_date datetime not null,
cust_id char(10)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

**order** it's a reserved word and put **char** instead of chat. You can name the table orders

Comment: On SO, when a question is the result of a typo, the typo is pointed out in the comments (as I did) and then we vote to close the question as off-topic due to a typographical error. The reason we do this is that an answer to the question does not tend to help any other users.

Comment: my reputation is low that's why I did here. Sorry for my mistake

Comment: No problem at all. I made the same mistake myself on earlier occasions.